# how to change mysql8.0 port

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have installed MySQL 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.0. I want to change default port 3306 to xxxxx.

I need help how to do that i am not able to see any comments on /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: Not so much programming, try asking here: https://askubuntu.com/